# Create multiple DataFrames with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a DataFrame containing aggregated price data for lease deals on a particular vehicle.

I need to compare this data to the current price (let's call it 100), using aggregations over various time ranges (in days) for the comparison.

I'm trying to create code that will output a single-row DataFrame with a column showing the percentage difference of the current price, to the median value for lag (in days) in the 'cutoffs' array.

I'm picturing an output like this:

| two_day | four_day | six_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.2 | -0.4 | -0.6 |

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['2021-11-16','250'],['2021-11-17','225'],['2021-11-18','200'],['2021-11-19','175'],['2021-11-20','150'],['2021-11-21','125']], columns = ['export_date','price'])

curr_price = 100

cutoffs = [2,4,6]

for c in cutoffs:
    cutoff_date = data["export_date"].max() - pd.Timedelta(days=c)
```

I'm sorry to say this is where I'm up to. Could use of dicts help here?

If there's any other info I can provide please let me know :)

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: @KrishnaGupta "I'm trying to create code that will output a single-row DataFrame with a column showing the percentage difference of the current price, to the median value for lag (in days) in the 'cutoffs' array." (expected output table directly below that)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['2021-11-16','250'],['2021-11-17','225'],['2021-11-18','200'],['2021-11-19','175'],['2021-11-20','150'],['2021-11-21','125']], columns = ['export_date','price'])

curr_price = 100

cutoffs = [2,4,6]

for c in cutoffs:
    cutoff_date = df2["export_date"].max() - pd.Timedelta(days=c)
```

Use this transpose in the end it will convert your 3 output rows data into columns data.

```
    cutoff_date .transpose()
```